# Creating a text arrow in Excel that moves down as questions are answered

Tags: excel, formula, poker

[image: Screenshot]

As shown in the 'Question' column, there is a **-->**

I need a formula that I can repeat to all cells in the column that will make a **-->** appear where the previous question has been answered ('N' cell of previous row is not blank) -

This would be simple enough with something like, for `G3`:

```
=IF(N2<>"", "-->", "")
```

The only catch is, I want only one **-->** arrow in the column to be visible at one time, so that when `G5` is displaying a **-->**, the **-->** in `G4` disappears - and I've found myself completely stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula in cell **G2** and copy down:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(G$1:G1,"-->")=0,N2=""),"-->","")
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!